# SQLAlchemy: Why I raise HTTPFound will cause no data be inserted into database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I built a view which allow user input some information and inserted that information as a new record into my database with Pyramid framework. The code is like this:

```
def orderplace_view(request):
    user = User.get(authenticated_userid(request))
    cart = Cart.get_by_user(user)

    if cart.itemtypes == None:  # cat is empty
        request.session.flash(u'Empty cart')
        raise HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('cart'))

    placeorderform = PlaceOrderForm(request.POST)
    placeorderform.address.query = UserAddress.query_by_user(user)

    if request.POST and placeorderform.validate():
        # create order
        order = Order()
        order.address = placeorderform.address.data

        # fill order with other attributes...
        user.orders.append(order)

        # IMPORTANT LINE!!!
        raise HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('order_list'))

    return {'user': user,
        'title': 'place order',
        'cart': cart,
        'placeorderform': placeorderform}
```

Here's the strange thing: If I commented out the "raise HTTPFound()" line, everything works fine, a new order would be inserted into database. But if I keep that line which redirect user to Order List page, the order won't be inserted! Why this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Pyramid transaction middleware is in use, it will abort the containing transaction when view function raises an exception: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tm/en/latest/#transaction-usage

Commit explicitly with `transaction.commit()`, or, better yet, return `HTTPFound` instead of raising it.

Comment: I tried to commit it but failed -- although I executed transaction.commit(), the record still not inserted into database. However, the return method works. Do you mind explain to me the difference between return a exception class and raising it? Thanks!

Comment: I found this on [Pyramid cookbook](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html) -- "The pyramid.httpexceptions module has classes for all official HTTP statuses. These classes inherit from both Response and Exception, so you can **either return them or raise them**. Raising HTTP exceptions can make your code structurally more readable." It seems the 'raise' method is recommended...

Comment: HTTP exceptions are just a convenience shortcut. Views generally should return valid response objects, and `HTTPxxx` family of classes are such. Returning non-200 HTTP status code often *is* an abnormal termination of control flow (you've encountered an error condition and report it back to the user), and using exceptions makes it explicit in the code.

Comment: I am sorry but @rkhayrov you still not told me the differences between return a httpexception and raise it.

Comment: There are none from the Pyramid core POV. The result is the same. However, as you can see from this transaction management example, exceptions may affect interactions with middleware.